# Using WebDAV to copy Tridion Page

Tags: webdav

Was wondering..... how come webdav can be used to copy everything but not Tridion pages or anything in the structure group? Any insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a long history, and I my mind does not recall R5.0 (and maybe even before that) too well, but you have only ever been able to access content with WebDAV.

WebDAV is designed for authoring and versioning documents (like images or text). The fact that a page can consist of multiple component presentations, means it is not really a single document, so the concept of authoring pages was left to what is now the CME or XPM.

Nowadays, very few people really use WebDAV on Tridion for the original intended purpose (I.e editing and creating content with native applications like XMLSpy and Photoshop) , but that is my insight on why it was never implemented for pages.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Chris! The original intend was to introduce alternative methods to end user to migrate content. For some reason, people just don't like using Content Porter so I thought about mounting the webdav path for them

Comment: Copy and paste in the Content Manager Exploer and even certain BluePrint changes can help with page copies (temporarily rewire a Publication and then copy pages). But even with WebDAV, you'd still have issues with dependencies. There's also the Content Porter API is if you're looking to script additional help. :-)